# How to run Curl Command in Python

Tags: python, curl

I want to run Following Curl Command in Python and I was trying the requests command of python but I am not getting the proper results.

`curl -v ftp://ftp.abc.com/File.txt --socks5-hostname socks.abc.com:PORT --user username:password -O`

Comment: what do you try to do and why you can not do it in python?

Answer (score 1):

You can use subprocess.

```
import subprocess
result = subprocess.run(["curl", "-v", "ftp://ftp.abc.com/File.txt --socks5-hostname socks.abc.com:PORT --user username:password -O"], capture_output=True)
print(result.stdout)
```

I'm not into web development but this looks like something the requests module should be able to handle.

```
r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=('user', 'pass'))
r.status_code
```

https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/